# Example such that $P_*(A)= P_*(A^c) = 1$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

For as given set $A$ define probability of $A$ as:

$P_∗(A) = \inf \{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |I_k| :$ each $I_k $ is an interval and $\{I_k\}$ a countable cover for $A\}$ .

Then to construct an example of a nonempty set $A \subset[0,1]$ such that $P_*(A)$ and $P_*(A^c)$ both equals to $1$.

It is evident that the set $A$ must be non measurable.

Comment: $P(A)+P(A^c)=1$...

Comment: Can you clarify your question? As it stands, there is clearly no such $A$.

Comment: I have edited ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick question: $P_*$ is not a measure and $A$ need not be measurable, so there is no contradiction in the posing of the question.  Instead, $P_*(A)$ is the  outer measure of $A$. You could let $H$ be a non measurable subset of $\mathbb R$, such as a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$, and let $A=H\cap[0,1]$. (You might have to doctor $A$  a bit to make it and its compliment both dense in $[0,1]$, by using instead something like $[0,1]\cap((H\setminus (\mathbb Q+\pi))\cup \mathbb Q)$.) The ordinary outer measure of $A$ is $P_*(A)=1$, and the outer measure of $A^c$ is $P_*(A^c)=1$.